# Number value is getting changed in JS

Tags: javascript

This is my post id:

```
var postId = 47213486358396931;
var postComments = "Comment";
```

adding in object like this

```
var param = {
    "PostId" : postId,
    "postComment":postComments
}
```

If I print the param I get  like this. The last digit of number changed to 0. Why am getting like this.

```
{"PostId" : 47213486358396930, "postComment": "Comment"}
```

Comment: `47213486358396931 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. This behavior is by design.

Comment: Holy crap, did you made 47213486358396931 posts? If you are want to pass it, pass it as a string `'47213486358396931'`

Comment: Further information (and tips to work around this!) can be found here: http://blog.vjeux.com/2010/javascript/javascript-max_int-number-limits.html